# How to integrate Oracle Advanced Queue with Websphere 7.0

Tags: oracle, jms, websphere, jca

IBM Websphere documentation says that It's possible to use third-party jms providers: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.nd.doc%2Finfo%2Fae%2Fae%2Ftmj_instp.html

In oracle folder I've found resource adapter ojms.rar, but how to use it?
Maybe somebody uses WAS7 with AQ?

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used OracleAQ myself, but here are links to the documentation; Since AQ is JCA compliant you may start with [Managing messaging with a third-party JCA 1.5-compliant messaging provider](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/tmp_ep_ra.html). First step of this configuration is [installing the resource adapter](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/tdat_crtresadp.html) (ojms.rar).

Also, for sake of completeness, let me add that you may also access AQ using [WebSphere Adapters](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/integration/wbiadapters/index.html?S_TACT=105AD02W&S_CMP=campaign&). In this case, you don't configure AQ as JMS provider, but use the IBM suuplied adapter to access AQ, which acts as a client to your AQ and exposes AQ services to your applications in a JCA compliant fashion. You may find more information about this alternative at education assistant for [WebSphere Adapter for Oracle E-Business Suite](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/ieduasst/v1r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.iea.wa_v7/wa/7.0/Oracle.html).

Answer (score 0):

I recently tried to integrate Websphere with Oracle AQ and found one solution that works. I have explained how to do it in a Blog. http://itsolutionsarchitect.blogspot.com/

If you are still trying to get this to work, let me know if this helps.

Comment: Please add this as comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still looking for the answer, follow the steps to install  the resource adapter using `ojms.rar`

Sadly `ojms.rar`` doesn't contain the classes required for installation.

Download `mqjra.rar`, extract it and take out `gjra.jar` from the extracted files.

Place `gjra.jar` inside your `<WAS installation directory>\lib`

Try to install the Resource adapter `with ojms.rar`

It'll get installed. Revert if you face issues.